# How to use Promise with nested foreach

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sequelize.js

I am finding all users wallets in nested foreach loop but i am unable to figure out where to use resolve() for return callback,

```
function genwallets() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    var i = 0;
    try {
        db.users.findAll({}).then((users)=>{
            db.supportedTokens.findAll({}).then((tokens)=>{ 
                users.forEach(function(user) {
                    tokens.forEach(function(token) {
                    db.wallets.findOne({where:{userId: user['id'], supportedTokenId: token['id']}}).then((wallet)=>{
                        console.log(JSON.stringify(wallet));
                    })
                    });
                });
            })
        });

    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
});
}
```

Comment: Use it after forEach. forEach isn't async

Comment: did you check this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53892863/how-to-wait-a-promise-inside-a-foreach-loop

Comment: You might want to rewrite that nested structure as well

Comment: If you are using `Promise` then why are you creating a [callback hell](http://callbackhell.com/) scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`forEach` doesn't work with promises. either use `for...of` or `Promise.all` something like this

```
function genwallets() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    var i = 0;
    try {
      db.users.findAll({}).then(users => {
        db.supportedTokens.findAll({}).then(tokens => {
          for(const user of users) {
            for(const token of tokens) {
              db.wallets
                .findOne({
                  where: { userId: user["id"], supportedTokenId: token["id"] }
                })
                .then(wallet => {
                  console.log(JSON.stringify(wallet));
                });
            }
          }
        });
      });
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  });
}
```

by the way you dont need to wrap it in promise.

You could simplify this using `async/await`

```
async function genwallets() {
  const users = await db.users.findAll({});
  const tokens = await db.supportedTokens.findAll({});

  for(const user of users) {
    for(const token of tokens) {
      const wallet = await db.wallets
        .findOne({
          where: { userId: user["id"], supportedTokenId: token["id"] }
        });
    }
  }
}
```