# Check if all entries exist in table

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

Good Day,

I am using Sequelize mysql in nodeJs.

My problem is that, given an array of IDs such as [4,5,6,7,8]

And a table T where each row holds a ID. say, 
Table T:

ID

4

5

7

8

How do I search if all the ID in the array exist in the table?

Do i do a for loop and call find on every loop? Is this done asynchronously or synchronously? How do i wrap it in a promise if i want to do that?

I am not sure what is the proper way for searching if all IDs given an array exist in the table.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

```sql
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT id) = 5       -- the values amount in the array
FROM sourcetable
WHERE FIND_IN_SET(id, '4,5,6,7,8')  -- the array as CSV literal
```

This query will return 1 record with one field. Value `1` means that all array elements are present, `0` - that at least one element is absent.

Array must NOT contain duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

foreach loop will not work so go with for loop example here following

```
  const ids =  [4,5,6,7,8];
  for (const id of ids) {
    db.T
      .findOne({
        where: { id: id }
      }).then()
  }
```

Comment: Do i need to wrap it in a promise or something to do with promises?

Comment: promise and async function both will work just foreach loop is not async

Comment: i asked same this question few days ago you check that one as well https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60706243/how-to-use-promise-with-nested-foreach?noredirect=1#comment107405806_60706243

Answer (score 0):

I think you can easily reach this with a findAll or a count. You provide the ids and ask to return them from DB if the number of items match you should be fine

```
model.findAll({
  where: {
    Id: {
      [Op.or]: [4,5,6,7,8]
    }
  }
});
```

You can do the same with count if you don't need the objects back